# Apollo-Server resolver chaining for thousands of requests

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

For the example below say I have 1000 people. It would mean I am calling getJobsById endpoint 1000 times when this query is fired per client. That seems problematic to me as the endpoint would do it's own lookups in MongoDb and fill the request queue. I feel I would have move Jobs out of this resolver chain and pass it an array of people Ids I want the jobs for. Wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this. Thanks!

**Query:**

```
Query {
 People {
   Id,
   Name
   Jobs {
     Id
     Name
   }
 }
}
```

**Schema:**

```
type People {
  id: ID
  name: String
  Job: Jobs
}

type Jobs {
  id: ID
  name: String
}

type Query {
  people: People
}
```

**Resolvers:**

```
export const Query = { 
  async people(_, args, context, info) {
     const { getAllPeople } = context.dataSources;
     return await getAllPeople();
}

export const People = { 
   async Jobs(parent, args, context) {
     const { getJobsById } = context.dataSources;
     return await getJobsById(parent.id);
  }
}
```